# Escaping single quotes by double single quotes doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, resourcebundle

I have recently added french translations for my application messages. These French translations have many single quotes in their text.

I am using Spring's ApplicationContext#getMessage(String, Object[], Locale) to resolve them.

The initial problem I faced was that these single quotes were not appearing on UI.

eg:- so

> n'est

is got displayed as

> nest

I came to know that single needs to represented as double single quotes in the resource bundles. i.e

> ''

But seems its not guaranteed. Some of the messages render properly like

> n'est

but some messages render with the double single quotes as is

> n''est

I don't know why this is happening.
.

Comment: why not simply escape the single quotes with a backslash?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

you cannot give a single `'` so,
Try this, `"n'est"`.